# handle exceptions

Tags: android, exception

I write a client for web service. Like, did request -> got `JSON` answer.
But if user not authorized I got "bad" `JSON` answer and `NullPointerException`. Further, the logic is create `ListAdapter` for a `ListView` from JSON answer. But if `JSON` null then app will crash.
I want do like this for handle exception:
**Get Adapter**:

```
public mListAdapter getData(String api){
    mListAdapter result = null;
    MyData[][] mData = null;
    try{
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(getJSONData(api)); 
 // getJSONData, here i can get Exception and return null, but i read what control of logic via exception is bad practice
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("NullPointerException", "error");
        return result;
    }
    result = new mListAdapter(title, mData);    
    return result;
}
```

**getJSONData**:

```
  public InputStream getJSONData(String url) throws NullPointerException{
    InputStream data = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        data = response.getEntity().getContent();
 //if (response.getEntity().getContent().getStatus()==404) return null, for example
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return data;
  }
```

**And set** `Adapter` **to** `ListView`:

```
if (adapter!=null) IWatchList.setAdapter(adapter); else IWatchList.setEmptyView(new TextView(this));
```

I don't like this method, because:
- I came up it.
- First two methods universal, therefore each adapter need describe like third method, this is not comfortably. On the other hand how else to define the adapter is empty or not! Only if check it.

Please, your pros and cons, proposal and tips how better and why.